# Issue with VBA .offset number

Tags: vba

I have been searching for an hour or so and I can't seem to find anything on this issue.  I may be wording it wrong so I'm not getting the results im looking for.  I am having an issue with .offset (, 99).  It seems that any time I put a like digit in there such as 99, 88, 11 or whatever combo there is, it raises runtime error 13 *type mismatch*.

But when I change it to 98 or any other non like combo it works fine. Is there some way that I need to program it if it has the same number multiple times?

```
Sub Scope()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Future Ongoing Vetting") ' change to name of your sheet

    Dim x As Long
        x = 2

    Do Until ws.Cells(x, 7) = ""

        With ws.Cells(x, 5)

            .Value = "• Customer name: " & .Offset(, 29) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Customer Bus Org: " & .Offset(, 30) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Internal Circuit ID: " & .Offset(, 2) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Customer prem address: " & .Offset(, 12) & " " & .Offset(, 13) & " " & .Offset(, 14) & ", " & .Offset(, 15) & ", " & .Offset(, 16) & ", " & .Offset(, 17) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Customer demarc: " & .Offset(, 18) & " " & .Offset(, 20) & ", " & .Offset(, 19) & " " & .Offset(, 21) & _
            Chr(10) & "• MRR: " & .Offset(, 68) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Current Off Net MRC: $" & .Offset(, 10) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Margin Percent: " & .Offset(, 89) & _
            Chr(10) & "• Bandwidth: " & .Offset(, 6) & " ( " & .Offset(, 7) & "Mb )" & _
            Chr(10) & "• Customer term end date: ""TEXT(.Offset(, 32),""mmm-dd-yyyy"")" & _
            Chr(10) & "• New Vendor: " & .Offset(, 106) & _
            Chr(10) & "• New MRC: $" & .Offset(, 102) & _
            Chr(10) & "• New NRC: $" & .Offset(, 103) & _
            Chr(10) & "• New Install Interval: " & .Offset(, 105) & _
            Chr(10) & "• New Term: " & .Offset(, 104) & _
            Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Planner Notes: This project is replacing the existing " & .Offset(, 6) & " ( " & .Offset(, 7) & "Mb ) based solution from ( " & .Offset(, 5) & " ) with a new " & .Offset(, 99) '& " ( " & .Offset(, 100) & "Mb ) based solution from ( " & .Offset(, 106) & " )."
    '        Chr(10) & "RFA # " & .Offset(, 107) & " install notes: " & _
    '        Chr(10) & "Please install ( " & .Offset(, 31) & " ) Ethernet " & .Offset(, 99) & " ( " & .Offset(, 100) & "Mb  ) circuit with ( " & .Offset(, 106) & " ) from ( " & .Offset(, 101) & " )  to ( [Customer Prem] " & .Offset(, 12) & " " & .Offset(, 13) & " " & .Offset(, 14) & ", " & .Offset(, 15) & ", " & .Offset(, 17) & " )."
    '        Chr(10) & "This new circuit will be used to replace existing customer circuit ECCKT: ""&RC[1]&"", ""&RC[109]&"", ""&RC[110]&"", ICCKT: "" & RC[2] & ""." & _
    '        Chr(10) & "The customer prem address is ( ""&RC[12]&"" ""&RC[13]&"" ""&RC[14]&"", ""&RC[15]&"", ""&RC[16]&"", ""&RC[17]&"" ) and customer demarc is ( ""&RC[18]&"" ""&RC[20]&"", ""&RC[19]&"" ""&RC[21]&"" )."



        End With

        x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: There is something else going on there. If you post some code we might be able to spot it.

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. Edit it into your question. Also, your problem likely has little to do with `offset` per se.

Comment: The starting range is very important.  Chance are that `Offset` is trying to extend your range beyond the boundaries of the worksheet.

Comment: "it seems to error out" isn't very informative. What is the actual error?

Comment: run time error 13. type mismatch

Comment: What's the value of the cell at that offset? What type is it?

Comment: the value is 100BASE-T.  I had it as a vlookup but also pasted as values and made sure it was set to general.

Comment: Are you setting the cells value or it's formula?  `TEXT(.Offset(, 32),""mmm-dd-yyyy"")` ` ""&RC[12]&"" ""&RC[13]&"" ""&RC[14]&"", ""&RC[15]`   Seem to suggest that you want to add a formula to the cell

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in a way that makes it very difficult to debug. I would recommend replacing that extremely long statement by:

```
Dim s As String 'at the top of the module, and then in the loop ...

s  = "• Customer name: " & .Offset(, 29)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Customer Bus Org: " & .Offset(, 30)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Internal Circuit ID: " & .Offset(, 2)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Customer prem address: " & .Offset(, 12) & " " & .Offset(, 13) & " " & .Offset(, 14) & ", " & .Offset(, 15) & ", " & .Offset(, 16) & ", " & .Offset(, 17)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Customer demarc: " & .Offset(, 18) & " " & .Offset(, 20) & ", " & .Offset(, 19) & " " & .Offset(, 21)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• MRR: " & .Offset(, 68)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Current Off Net MRC: $" & .Offset(, 10)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Margin Percent: " & .Offset(, 89)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Bandwidth: " & .Offset(, 6) & " ( " & .Offset(, 7) & "Mb )"
s = s & Chr(10) & "• Customer term end date: ""TEXT(.Offset(, 32),""mmm-dd-yyyy"")"
s = s & Chr(10) & "• New Vendor: " & .Offset(, 106)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• New MRC: $" & .Offset(, 102)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• New NRC: $" & .Offset(, 103)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• New Install Interval: " & .Offset(, 105)
s = s & Chr(10) & "• New Term: " & .Offset(, 104)
s = s & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Planner Notes: This project is replacing the existing " & .Offset(, 6) & " ( " & .Offset(, 7) & "Mb ) based solution from ( " & .Offset(, 5) & " ) with a new " & .Offset(, 99) '& " ( " & .Offset(, 100) & "Mb ) based solution from ( " & .Offset(, 106) & " )."

.Value = s
```

Splitting the needlessly long statement into a series of shorter statements will enable you to better pinpoint where the type mismatch error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer calling a function to build the string.  You'll be able isolate the code and debug it in the Immediate Window without.

Note:  I use `ws.Rows(5).Cells` to set a reference the cells in the row.  In this way; I can reference each column by it's actual column number not the offset of `Cells(RowNumber, 5)`.  It also allows me to use a shorthand method of referring to cells on that row.  e.g. `r(1)` refers to column 1 `r(10)` refers to column 10 of `Rows(RowNumber)`.

### [image]

```
Function getDescription(ws As Worksheet, RowNumber As Long) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Data(14)

    Set r = ws.Rows(5).Cells

    Data(0) = "• Customer name: " & r(34)
    Data(1) = "• Customer Bus Org: " & r(35)
    Data(2) = "• Internal Circuit ID: " & r(7)
    Data(3) = "• Customer prem address: " & r(17) & " " & r(18) & " " & r(19) & ", " & r(20) & ", " & r(21) & ", " & r(22)
    Data(4) = "• Customer term end date: " & Chr(34) & Format(r(37), "mmm-dd-yyyy") & Chr(34)
    Data(5) = "• Customer demarc: " & r(23) & " " & r(25) & ", " & r(24) & " " & r(26)
    Data(6) = "• MRR: " & r(73)
    Data(7) = "• Current Off Net MRC: $" & r(15)
    Data(8) = "• Margin Percent: " & r(94)
    Data(9) = "• Bandwidth: " & r(11) & " ( " & r(12) & "Mb )"
    Data(10) = "• New Vendor: " & r(111)
    Data(11) = "• New MRC: $" & r(107)
    Data(12) = "• New NRC: $" & r(108)
    Data(13) = "• New Install Interval: " & r(110)
    Data(14) = "• New Term: " & r(109)

    getDescription = Join(Data, Chr(10))

End Function
```

Comment: Animated gif. Cool. However they do it, OP needs to modularize that long statement so that its parts can be individually debugged.

Comment: I love ScreenToGif and have been trying to get better at using it. Yes, agreed.  I like this technique because it gets a lot of the ordinary fluff out of the way so that you can focus on the code line for line.

Comment: I figured it out! It was something stupid... I forgot that I had formulas in row two and the formulas in columns 99 and 100 were errored out.  In my mind i was thinking the code started on row 3... Ugh.  Thank you all for your suggestions, it was a great help and i got some great ideas.